# Using the ASH widow manager from Chrome OS

Tags: google-chrome, window-manager, chromeos

I was interested in using google chrome's ASH window manager on Ubuntu. I first tried [dz0ny's lightdm-login-chromeos project](https://github.com/dz0ny/lightdm-login-chromeos), but that seems to have been abandoned. I then tried the `google-chrome --open-ash command`with the Chrome browser installed, but that had many bugs. Are there any other options available?